# How to ban a random player from discord using discord bot?

Tags: python, list, random, discord, discord.py

I am making a Russian roulette function on my discord bot.
You enter a list of players and it bans one of them.

Here is some pseudo-code I wrote:

```
elif message.content.startswith("!Russian"):
    l = []
    l.append(input("Enter a name"))
    l.append(input("Enter a name"))
    l.append(input("Enter a name"))
    l.append(input("Enter a name"))
    l.append(input("Enter a name"))
    l.append(input("Enter a name"))
    playertoban = l[random.randint(1, 6)]
    
    ban(playertoban) #I wanna make a function that bans playertoban for one day
```

Note: It should only ban one of the players for only one day.

Here's the whole code

```
import discord
import os
import random

from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith("!calculate"):
    var = message.content
    var = var.replace("!calculate", "")
    var = var.replace(" ", "")
    var = var.replace("^", "**")
    var = var.replace("x", "*")
    var = var.replace("X", "*")
    try:
      result = eval(var)
      await message.channel.send(str(result))
    except:
       await message.channel.send("That is not a valid equation")
  elif message.content.startswith("!spam"):
    if "plane" in message.content:
      c = -1
      for i in range(100):
        stre = ""
        c = c + 1
        for h in range(c):
          stre = stre + "-"
        stre = stre + ":airplane_departure:"

        await message.channel.send(stre)    
    elif "boat" in message.content:
      c = -1
      for i in range(100):
        stre = ""
        c = c + 1
        for h in range(c):
          stre = stre + "-"
        stre = stre + ":man_rowing_boat:"

        await message.channel.send(stre)   
  elif message.content.startswith("!Er") or message.content.startswith("!Har") or message.content.startswith("!Vil") or message.content.startswith("!Hadde") or message.content.startswith("!Skal") or message.content.startswith("!Kommer") or message.content.startswith("!Tenker"):
    re = random.randint(1, 10)
    if re == 1:
      await message.channel.send("Ja")
    elif re == 2: 
      await message.channel.send("Nei")
    elif re == 3:
      await message.channel.send("Kanskje")
    elif re == 4:
      await message.channel.send("Vanskelig å si")
    elif re == 5:
      await message.channel.send("Definetivt!")
    elif re == 6:
      await message.channel.send("Sannsynligvis")
    elif re == 7:
      await message.channel.send("Antagelig ikke...")
    elif re == 8:
      await message.channel.send("Heck no!")
    elif re == 9:
      await message.channel.send("Hell ye!")
    elif re == 10:
      await message.channel.send("Vet ikke, men skal tenke litt på det")
```

I need help with the banning part I already know the picking who part.

Comment: Just a suggestion for your inputs you could also do something like this `l = [input('Enter a name:') for _ in range(6)]`

Comment: Okay, so what part of this don't you know how to do? And what happened when you checked the documentation?

Comment: I need help with making a function that bans players when I call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `on_message` for commands.

Once you have got the player name, you would want to get the [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object.

Then you would want to ban them, with deleting messages for 0 days. Record the datetime of the time in 1 day. Then add them to a database/json file. Then use a [Tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html) to check if it has reached that time then unban them then remove them from the database/json file.

Answer (score 0):

Like FluxedScript says, you probably want to use a [`discord.py` command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) rather than using `on_message`. If you do so, you could try this:

```py
import random

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks


class DiscordBot(commands.Bot):
    
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.intents.default()
        intents.members = True
        self.bot = commands.Bot(prefix="!", intents=intents)

        self.bot.add_cog(RussianRoulette(self.bot))


class RussianRoulette(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.banned = {}

    @commands.command(name="russian", *names)
    async def russian(self, ctx):
        members_list = [discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, name=n) for n in names]
        member = random.choice(member_list)
        member.ban(reasion="Russian Roulette")
        self.banned.setdefault(
            member,
            datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        )

    @tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
    async def check_unban(self):
        for mem, dtime in self.banned.items():
            if datetime.datetime.now() <= dtime:
                mem.unban(reason="Ban expired")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    bot = DiscordBot()
    loop.add_task(bot.start("TOKEN"))
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Now this assumes that your bot instance is properly set up. You will also need to activate some [gateway intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

Comment: There is an error with check_unban:

Comment: ```File "main.py", line 96
    async def check_unban(self):
          ^```

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad, @Miklath. I forgot a closing parenthesis on the `setdefault()` call.

Comment: Could I send you the whole thing? I get a lot of errors...

Comment: @Miklath I don't know what you mean by "the whole thing". Don't you already have a bot initialized? If you're getting a lot of errors, I would need to know what *kind* of error is being raised in order to fix the code I have provided.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I fixed it. I just forgot to tell you/accept.